# Encapsulate a set of Google calendars

Tags: google-calendar

As a user of Google Calendar, I can set up my account to display a set of individual calendars (say three ... Ron's, Jeff's and Conf Room A's).

Is there any way to encapsulate this set of calendars and expose it?

The goal would be to be able to put a single link on a web page that, when clicked, would display a single view with the three calendars (Ron's, Jeff's and Conf Room A's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar need, and was able to create an "aggregate" calendar from several individual calendars.

This fellow has laid out the steps very nicely: https://web.archive.org/web/20180728073609/http://murphymac.com/share-busy-free-info-for-multiple-google-calendars/

Comment: 's link is down please see https://web.archive.org/web/20180728073609/http://murphymac.com/share-busy-free-info-for-multiple-google-calendars/ (don't have enough rep to comment)