# Sharing combined free/busy schedule in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consolidating google calendars](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/consolidating-google-calendars)

I have multiple calendars eg. private and work. I have them publish my free/busy times. But it's worthless and unusable unless someone subscribes to my all calendars - very, very inconvenient.

I looking for means to show someone my free/busy schedule, by ONE url, with all my calendars combined. This way I could email them this link any time I'm trying to schedule an event.

Or, id like to share my calendars other Google Calendar user but as one free/busy calendar visible under my name, and not all these: John - Work, John - Private, Soccer Team, Community Events.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/multi-account-google-apps-calendar-free-busy-status

Comment: Possibly related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/encapsulate-a-set-of-google-calendars